# Error [MSB3246] after adding MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 7 to app in DotNetCore 6

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Using EntityFramework7 on DotNetCore6 (also tried upgrading to DotNetCore7 and it didn't fix anything).  Although the app compiles and seems to run fine, having warnings every build concerns me.  When doing DotNet build the error is (repeated 5 times).

```
  Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2352, 5): [MSB3246] Resolved file has a bad image, no metadata, or is otherwise inaccessible. System.BadImageFormatException: PE image does not have metadata.
   at System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataReader.GetAssemblyName(String assemblyFile)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.AssemblyNameExtension.GetAssemblyNameEx(String path)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.SystemState.GetAssemblyName(String path)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.SetPrimaryAssemblyReferenceItem(ITaskItem referenceAssemblyName)
```

Which confused me, since it didn't specify the file it was having problems with.  Eventually when I went run publish on our CI server I got more useful information:

```
    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.405/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3246: Resolved file has a bad image, no metadata, or is otherwise inaccessible. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly '/home/jenkins/.nuget/packages/mysql.data/8.0.32/lib/net6.0/comerr64.dll'. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. [/home/jenkins/workspace/dashboard/dashboard.csproj]
    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.405/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3246: File name: '/home/jenkins/.nuget/packages/mysql.data/8.0.32/lib/net6.0/comerr64.dll' [/home/jenkins/workspace/dashboard/dashboard.csproj]
    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.405/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3246:    at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.nGetFileInformation(String s) [/home/jenkins/workspace/dashboard/dashboard.csproj]
    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.405/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3246:    at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(String assemblyFile) [/home/jenkins/workspace/dashboard/dashboard.csproj]
    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.405/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3246:    at Microsoft.Build.Shared.AssemblyNameExtension.GetAssemblyNameEx(String path) [/home/jenkins/workspace/dashboard/dashboard.csproj]
    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.405/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3246:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveAssemblyReference.<>c.<Execute>b__255_3(String p) [/home/jenkins/workspace/dashboard/dashboard.csproj]
    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.405/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3246:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.SystemState.GetAssemblyName(String path) [/home/jenkins/workspace/dashboard/dashboard.csproj]
    /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.405/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3246:    at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.SetPrimaryAssemblyReferenceItem(ITaskItem referenceAssemblyName) [/home/jenkins/workspace/dashboard/dashboard.csproj]
```

Which made me realize that it was MySql that was the problem.

I tried downgrading to MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 6 but I get the same error.  Removing MySql.EntityFrameworkCore (and switching to Microsoft.EntityFrameWorkCore.Sqlite) the error goes away.  Is there anything that can be done about this or is it safe to ignore the errors.

Comment: Are you sure the error has anything to do with .NET 7 or EF Core 7? That error means that something tried to use a file that *isn't* a valid binary. There may have been an attempt to load a Linux instead of a Linux library, a 32-bit instead of 64-bit.

Comment: MySQL and SQLite are two completely different databases - SQLite is an embedded, single-client database, MySQL is a server-based database. You can't use the drivers for one to connect to the other

Comment: Before the edit you showed Windows paths, after the edit it's Linux paths. I suspect that somehow, the project is referencing the wrong libraries if not even the wrong packages, directly. The information is the same as before - the wrong binary is being loaded

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I updated the comment.  You can use two different databases in EF as long as they have different DSNs.  I frequently develop on Sqlite and then move to MySql mostly to ensure I am doing portable EF development and not attaching myself to one database.  That is one of the advantages of EF is being able to run it on different databases.  Yes our CI server is a Linux machine, and it gives more useful information about the build (all the bad MySql dlls which windows doesn't builds don't mention).  Like I said, I take out Mysql.EntityFramework and no errors.

Comment: Are you using Oracle's MySQL drivers? Those are a bit ... buggy. Quite a bit actually. I strongly suggest using the truly open source [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/) package. That, and the related MySqlConnector package are actually *more* popular than Oracle's packages, actively maintained and fix a *lot* of the bugs in Oracle's drivers

Comment: `as long as they have different DSNs.` it's not DSNs, it's different driver registrations and connection strings, eg `UseSqlite` vs `UseMySql`. Instead of trying to find out whether you encountered a bug in Oracle's drivers, use the open source ones. Just one of the differences is true async support

Comment: In the 7.0 wave, Pomelo has 47K downloads while Oracle's just 6K.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I switched to the Pomelo and the problems went away.  Post that as the answer and I will accept it to help people in the future so they don't have to read the comments.

Comment: I did. I found the Pomelo guys already reference this bug and describe a fix!

Comment: I came across this using the MySql.data nuget package, version  8.0.32.  It's only a warning, so I could live with it.  But an annoying warning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems [this is a known bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=109716) in Oracle's drivers. The error suggests that a non-Linux binary was included in the build. Oracle's MySQL drivers have several known problems, which is why most developers use the truly open-source [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) provider and the related [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) ADO.NET provider.

The open source driver fixes a lot of the serious problems in Oracle's drivers, in fact they make a point of it. For example, they [reference this very bug with a fix](https://mysqlconnector.net/troubleshooting/failed-add-reference-comerr/). They also have a [migration guide with a long list of fixed bugs](https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/)

In the 7.0 wave, the Pomelo driver has 47K downloads while Oracles only 6.5K